# "Merge with caution" on github

Tags: github

I noticed that that on my pull request in github it now says "Merge with caution", while still allowing me to auto-merge. Appears to have something to do with https://circleci.com, to which the Failed(details) link right above redirects. Anyone knows what this is all about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project has probably been configured to be linked with an online continuous integration service which performs quality checks (are the unit tests passing, etc.) on pull requests.

So the message probably means: there's no conflict and you can merge, but the result will be a project with failing tests. Maybe you would discover more if you clicked on the link (or told us where the link point to precisely).